# Need help to frame locator for webdriver script

Tags: webdriver, xpath

I have a button `reach_analysis_button` with `id="x-auto-7"`.

But directly using that i am not able to locate the element from webdriver.

I tried `("//div(@class=’x-window-bwrap’)/div[@class=’x-window-ml’]/div[@class='x-window-mr']/div[@class=’x-window-mc’]/div[@role=’presentation’]/img[@id='x-auto-7']"))` but was of no use.

Finally what helped me was the following:

```
webdriven.findElement(By.id("welcomeWindow"));
webdriven.findElement(By.className("x-window-bwrap"));
webdriven.findElement(By.className("x-window-ml"));
webdriven.findElement(By.className("x-window-mr"));
webdriven.findElement(By.className("x-window-mc"));
WebElement Estimates=webdriven.findElement(By.id("x-auto-7"));
```

Following is the html of image button `reach_analysis_button` I am trying to click:

```
<div class="x-shadow x-ignore" style="display: block; z-index: 1011; left: 416px; top: 9px; width: 580px; height: 292px;">
<div id="welcomeWindow" class=" x-window x-component " style="position: absolute; width: 580px; left: 406px; top: 0px; z-index: 1012;" tabindex="0" hidefocus="true">
<div class="x-window-tl" role="presentation">
<div class="x-window-bwrap" role="presentation" style="overflow: auto; position: static;">
<div class="x-window-ml" role="presentation">
<div class="x-window-mr" role="presentation">
<div class="x-window-mc" role="presentation">
<div class="x-window-body x-abs-layout-container" role="presentation" style="width: 566px; height: 261px;">
<img id="x-auto-7" class="welcome-image x-component x-abs-layout-item" src="resources/images/arbitron/reach_analysis_button.jpg" style="left: 193px; top: 6px;">
<img id="x-auto-8" class="welcome-image x-component x-abs-layout-item" src="resources/images/arbitron/saved_insights_button.jpg" style="left: 380px; top: 6px;">
<img id="x-auto-9" class="welcome-image x-component x-abs-layout-item" src="resources/images/arbitron/behavior_analysis_button.jpg" style="left: 6px; top: 6px;">
```

I need a single line locator for this element, other than using those six lines, is it possible?

Comment: so what do you want answered?

Comment: I should suffice to use an xpath of "//*[@id='x-auto-7']".  Of course this the img element in question always has the same id.  The name "x-auto-7" suggests the ID is auto-generated, and my experience is that auto-generated IDs tend to change.

Comment: Ardesco I ran the test a few times but didn see the id changing , the problem is with directly locating to that xpath . If u see teh code i have given above, step by step geting to that location through the div hierarchy driver is able to locate  it , but directly  it cant

Comment: When I've had pages like this that are difficult to find I use Wait's to make sure the page is loaded, but looking for some text and then look for the page source.  I avoid XPath since I mostly test on IE but if it works for you then do it.

Comment: yes Michael, I been using the same script since and its working quiet consistently .

Comment: Can you clarify what element you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using regular expression or a substring in the xpath?

Something like this may help:

```
 xpath = "//img[contains(@id,'x-auto')]" OR
WebElement Estimates=webdriven.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@id,'x-auto')]"));
```

You can also use another xpath method starts-with(@id,'x-auto')

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using CSS selector to find the button as a descendent of the welcome window?

```
WebElement Estimates = webdriven.findElement(By.CssSelector("#welcomeWindow #x-auto-7"));
```